# How do I add unity script settings?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

how do I make a script, that when attached to an object, you can change the settings of it under the script, like a number value or string?

Comment: just add a public variable in the script, Unity will do the rest. Technically, Unity will only show  serializable types, but the basic types are all serializable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the variables in `public` visibility.

Source: [Variables and the Inspector](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/VariablesAndTheInspector.html)

For instance:

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MainPlayer : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public string myName;
    
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        Debug.Log("I am alive and my name is " + myName);
    }
}
```

You can now change "the settings" of the variable `myName` when attached to an object.

Answer (score 1):

There are basically two options, either making the variable public or using the [SerializeField] attribute. The best practice is to use [SerializeField] if you're not going to access the variable outside the class.

1: `public string exposedString;`

2: `[SerializeField] private string serializedString;`